# PHP-validation error message doesn’t go after the user refresh the page

Tags: php, html

Problem is: If I write the wrong input for example: under username the number of character must be from 2-25 and I write only one character then error is shown and after I refresh the page the error doesn't go. How to remove the validation error after I refresh the page. There are three files: register.php Account.php and register-handlers.php

**register.php**

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
    <?php
       include("includes/classes/Accounts.php");
        $account1  = new Accounts();



       include("includes/handlers/register-Handlers.php");

         ?>
    <html lang="en" dir="ltr">
       <head>
          <meta charset="utf-8">
          <title>Register your free account</title>
       </head>
       <body>
          <div id="inputContainer">
             <form id="loginForm" action="login.php" method="POST">
                <h2> Login to your account</h2>
                <p>
                   <label for="loginusername">Username</label>
                   <input type="text" id="loginusername" placeholder="eg:shaahil" required>
                </p>
                <p>
                   <label for="loginpassword">password</label>
                   <input type="password" id="loginpassword" placeholder="type your password" required>
                </p>
                <button type="submit" name="LOGINB">Login</button>
             </form>
          </div>
          <form id="registerpage" action="register.php" method="POST">
             <h2>Create your free account</h2>
             <p>
                <?php echo $account1 -> getError("the character must be between 5 to 25 "); ?>
                <label for="username1">Username</label>
                <input type="text" name="username1" id="username1" placeholder="username" required>
             </p>
             <p>
                <?php echo $account1->getError("your first name must have character between 2 to 25 ");?>
                <label for="firstname">First name</label>
                <input name="firstname" type="text" id="firstname" placeholder="eg:shaahil" required>
             </p>
             <p>
                <?php echo $account1->getError("your last name must have character between 2 to 25 ");?>
                <label for="lastname">Last name</label>
                <input name="lastname" type="text" id="lastname" placeholder="eg:abraham" required>
             </p>
             <p>
                <?php echo $account1->getError("invalid password ");?>
                <?php echo $account1->getError("abc");?>
                <?php echo $account1->getError("the password must be between 5 to 25 characters");?>
                <label for="password">Password</label>
                <input name="password" type="password" id="password" placeholder="enter your password" required>
             </p>
             <p>
                <label for="password1">Confirm password</label>
                <input name="password1" id="password1" type="password" placeholder="Confirm your password" required>
             </p>
             <p>
                <?php echo $account1->getError("Email is invalid");?>
                <label for="email1">Email</label>
                <input name="email1" type="email" id="email1" placeholder="enter your email" required>
             </p>
             <button type="submit" name="Registerbutton">Register</button>
          </form>
       </body>
    </html>
```

**register-handlers.php**

```
<?php
   function sanitizeFormUsername($inputText){
   $inputText = strip_tags($inputText);
   $inputText=str_replace(" ","",$inputText);
   $inputText=ucfirst(strtolower($inputText));
   return $inputText;
   }

   function sanitizeFormString($inputText){
   $inputText = strip_tags($inputText);

   $inputText=str_replace(" ","",$inputText);
   $inputText=ucfirst(strtolower($inputText));
   return $inputText;
   }

   function sanitizeFormEmail($inputText){
   $inputText=strip_tags($inputText);
   $inputText=str_replace(" ","",$inputText);
   return $inputText;
   }

   function sanitizeFormPassword($inputText){
   $inputText=strip_tags($inputText);
   return $inputText;
   }



   if(isset($_POST['Registerbutton'])){

   $username1 = sanitizeFormUsername($_POST['username1']);

   $firstname = sanitizeFormUsername($_POST['firstname']);

   $lastname = sanitizeFormUsername($_POST['lastname']);

   $email1 = sanitizeFormEmail($_POST['email1']);

   $password= sanitizeFormPassword($_POST['password']);

   $password1= sanitizeFormPassword($_POST['password1']);


   $wasSuccessful = $account1->register($username1, $firstname, $lastname, $email1, $password, $password1);
   if($wasSuccessful==true){
     header("Location: index.php");
   }
   ?>
```

**Accounts.php**

```
<?php
   class Accounts{
     private $errorArray;
     public function __construct(){

       $this->errorArray = array();


     }
     public function register($un1, $fn1, $ln, $em, $ps, $ps1)
     {
       $this->validateusername($un1);
       $this->validatefirstname($fn1);
       $this->validatelastname($ln);
       $this->validateemail1($em);
       $this->validatepasswords($ps,$ps1);
     if(empty($this->errorArray) == true){

          return true;
       }
       else {
         return false;
       }
       }


   public function getError($error) {
     if(!in_array($error, $this->errorArray)) {
       $error = "";
   }
     return " <span class='errorMessage'>$error</span> ";


   }

     private function validateusername($un){
        if(strlen($un) > 25 || strlen($un) < 5 ){
       array_push($this->errorArray , "the character must be between 5 to 25 ");
       return;
        }

   }

     private function validatefirstname($fn){
          if(strlen($fn) > 25 || strlen($fn) < 2){
            array_push($this->errorArray , "your first name must have character between 2 to 25 ");
            return;
       }
     }

     private function validatelastname($ln){
       if(strlen($ln)>25 || strlen($ln)<2){
         array_push($this ->errorArray , "your last name must have character between 2 to 25 ");
         return;

     }
   }
     private function validatepasswords($ps,$ps1){
       if($ps!=$ps1){
         array_push($this ->errorArray , "invalid password ");
         return;
       }


       if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9]/', $ps)) {
         array_push($this->errorArray, "abc");
         return;
       }

       if(strlen($ps)>25 || strlen($ps)<5){
           array_push($this->errorArray , "the password must be between 5 to 25 characters");
           return;
      }
    }


     private function validateemail1($em1){
       if(!filter_var($em1,FILTER_VALIDATE_EMAIL)){
           array_push($this ->errorArray , "Email is invalid");
           return;

       }


   }

   }


    ?>
```

Comment: Terminology is important here.  When you say refresh, do you mean re-submit, or refresh?

Comment: I mean when I write wrong input then validation error is shown ,when I refresh the page- when the page shows the validation error the error doesn’t go,  when I submit the form with correct input then the error goes away.

Comment: That sounds like the correct behaviour.  If however you refresh (after a form submission), you'll likely re-submit old values and get the same error messages.

Answer (score 0):

This is not an answer, but rather a suggestion.

You are probably better keying your errors array with something like the field name to make error message retrieval easier.

I've adapted one of your validation methods so that it's possible to add multiple errors per field:

```
<?php

class AccountValidator
{
    public $errors;

    public function validateLastname($ln)
    {
        if(strlen($ln)>25 || strlen($ln)<2){
            $this ->errors['lastname'][] =
            "Your last name must have between 2 and 25 characters.";

            return false;
        }
    }
}

$firstname = 'X';
$lastname  = 'O';

$validator = new AccountValidator;
if($validator->validateLastname($lastname) === false)
{
    echo
    '<ul><li>', 
    implode('</li><li>', $validator->errors['lastname']), 
    '</li></ul>';
}
```

Output:

```
<ul><li>Your last name must have between 2 and 25 characters.</li></ul>
```